# Presto query fails to insert data into Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, presto

I am trying to insert the data into hive. For this I am using Presto.

Here is my query:

```
insert into card_transactions_part_buck partition(tran_year,tran_month,tran_day)
select tran_id,
tran_uid,
tran_date,
tran_category,
tran_category_id,
tran_type,
tran_type_id,
tran_ingress_ip_address,
tran_ingress_api_name,
tran_ingress_api_id,
platform,
platform_id,
card_type,
card_type_id,
amount,re_amount,
fxrate,
currency,
currency_id,
term_provider,
term_provider_id,
term_merchant,
term_merchant_id,
term_spendcode,
term_spendcode_id,
term_ip_address,
term_country,
term_country_id,
term_countrycode,
term_stateregion,
term_stateregion_id,
term_city,term_city_id,
term_postcode,
cust_first_name,
cust_last_name,
cust_email,
cust_ip_address,
cust_city,
cust_city_id,
cust_postcost,
cust_country,
cust_country_id,
cust_address,
SUBSTR(tran_date,0,4) as tran_year,
SUBSTR(tran_date,6,2) as tran_month,
SUBSTR(tran_date,9,2) as tran_day
from card_transactions;
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Query 20180502_113622_00037_xt6fw failed: line 1:41: extraneous input 'partition' expecting {'.', '(', 'SELECT', 'TABLE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}
```

When I run same query in Hive shell it's working completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `partition(tran_year,tran_month,tran_day)`.

```
insert into card_transactions_part_buck 
select 
tran_id,
tran_uid,
tran_date,
tran_category,
tran_category_id,
tran_type,
tran_type_id,
tran_ingress_ip_address,
tran_ingress_api_name,
tran_ingress_api_id,
platform,
platform_id,
card_type,
card_type_id,
amount,re_amount,
fxrate,
currency,
currency_id,
term_provider,
term_provider_id,
term_merchant,
term_merchant_id,
term_spendcode,
term_spendcode_id,
term_ip_address,
term_country,
term_country_id,
term_countrycode,
term_stateregion,
term_stateregion_id,
term_city,term_city_id,
term_postcode,
cust_first_name,
cust_last_name,
cust_email,
cust_ip_address,
cust_city,
cust_city_id,
cust_postcost,
cust_country,
cust_country_id,
cust_address,
SUBSTR(tran_date,0,4) as tran_year,
SUBSTR(tran_date,6,2) as tran_month,
SUBSTR(tran_date,9,2) as tran_day
from card_transactions;
```